# How to use a CustomApplication class in a Flutter Plugin

Tags: android, flutter

I am generating a plugin in Flutter that will integrate a native library *.aar and this library needs to be initialized in the Application class of android, since it will extend the Application class of the library. The problem I am having is that at no time does it seem that the Application class is used in the Flutter plugin, I have tried to create the application class and define it in the plugin manifest, but at no time does it seem to enter the onCreate. I do not see how to solve this situation, any indication is welcome.

My class Application:

```
public class App extends SDKApplication{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.e("App", "onCreate");

    }
}
```

My manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".App">
</application>
```

and the plugin class:

```
public class SdkPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
  ///
  /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
  /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
  private MethodChannel channel;
  private EMTingSDK sdk = EMTingSDK.getInstance();
  private Context context;

  public SdkPlugin(){
    Log.e("PRUEBAS","onMethodCall");
    new App();
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    context = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
    channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), Constants.CHANNEL);
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    Log.e("PRUEBAS","onMethodCall");
    if (call.method.equals("getPlatformVersion")) {
      result.success("Android " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    }else {
      result.notImplemented();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
  }
}
```

P.D: I need to start it in the Application because the developers of the native library told us that it had to be spent in this way, then I will put a little more code regarding the application.

```
public class SDKApplication extends CompanyApplication implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    public SDKApplication() {
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        SDK.getInstance().setContext(this.getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("InfoSDK", "SDKApplication - init from App ");
        this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        SDK.getInstance().setHostActivity(activity);
    }

    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        SDK.getInstance().setHostActivity(activity);
    }

    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

And the Company Application is:

```
public class CompanyApplication extends Application {
    public CompanyApplication () {
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RequestQueue mainQueue = null;
        if (SDK.getInstance().isDevelopEnviroment()) {
            mainQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack((UrlRewriter)null, this.newSslSocketFactory()));
        } else {
            mainQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());
        }

        CompanyHttpClient.getInstance().setMainQueue(mainQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the library require you to extend application? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Hello @RichardHeap , I have edited the question a bit expanding the inheritance of the applications, so they told us the Volley library is initialized in its applications and it was necessary to use it in this way. Thanks for your comments